# How to use ngrx store in angular application

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am trying to use ngrx store in our project but due to some mistake it does not work, 
it has a simple checkbox button on click checkbox we use dispatch method but it does not call reducer  function 
my code is given below

main.reducer.ts

```
export function reducer(state,action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'product_code_toggle':
    console.log('existing state:' + JSON.stringify(state));
    console.log('payload:'+action.payload);
    return{
      ...state,
      showProductCode:action.payload
    }
    defoult:
    return state;
  }
}
```

main.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { reducer} from './state/main.reducer';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducer),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngrxexample';

  constructor(private store:Store<any>){

  }

  checkChange(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.store.dispatch({
      type:'product_code_toggle',
      payload:value
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)='checkChange($event.target.checked)'>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: are you using Effects?

Comment: @FatehMohamed  no

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue but... defoult is a typo